# Is it possible to access Linked accounts' instances from root account in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-billing

I can see the instance from my linked account in billing console. but I can't find where is that instance. is it possible to access linked account's instance from root account in AWS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not supported functionality within AWS according the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-console.html).

> You can only switch roles when you sign in as an IAM user. You cannot switch roles if you sign in as the AWS account root user.

You will need to create an AWS IAM user with the permissions of "Sts:AssumeRole" for the other account you would like to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, if you're managing multiple accounts, move to AWS Organization.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_accounts_access.html

> When you create an account in your organization, in addition to the root user, AWS Organizations automatically creates an IAM role that is by default named OrganizationAccountAccessRole.

That way it'll be a lot easier for you to manage your billing account and member accounts (as well as visibility on the organization level)